# How to clear/reset all child controls within a usercontrol from code behind asp net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I need to clear/Reset all my child controls within the UserControl used in my ASP.NET page.

Referred as

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="uclUserItinerary" Src="~/controls/UserItinerary.ascx" %>

<uc1:uclUserItinerary ID="UserItinerary" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a public method to your usercontrol (e.g. `ClearControls()`) Where you

- Reset the individual controls (`txtMyTextBox.Value = "";` etc.)

or

- Loop through all controls and reset them depending on their type.

```
 foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
 {
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)control).Text = "";
    }
    ....
}
```